# photoOutput() called with its error parameter set

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation

I followed the directions to capture, and store uncompressed (raw), image files at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/photo_capture/capturing_photos_in_raw_and_apple_proraw_formats
With the exception of excluding the thumbnails because they are not needed. When picture taking is attempted this completion handler callback method:

> RAWCaptureDelegate.photoOutput( _ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,  didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)

is called as expected, but called with its "error" parameter set to the value:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11803 "Cannot Record" UserInfo={AVErrorRecordingFailureDomainKey=3, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again.}

I do not know what to do about this error. The error message recommends trying again, but the error repeats every time.
Any suggestions on possible causes, or what diagnostics can be done to find out what is going wrong, would be much appreciated.

The device this is run on is an iPhone 14 pro.

Comment: Have you find any solution ? I am facing the same problem with iPhone X running iOS 16.7.4